# if $K/F$ is a Galois extension, show that any intermediate field $L$ is generated by the traces of elements from $K$ over $L$.

Tags: galois-theory

if $ K/F$ is a Galois extension,  show that any intermediate field $L$ is generated by the traces of $K$ over $L$.

We know that $K$ can be generated over $F$ by a single element, say $\alpha$, I guess the trace of $\alpha$ over $L$, namely $\Sigma_{\sigma \in Gal(K/L)}(\sigma(\alpha))$, generates $L$ over $F$, but I have been unable to prove it. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Dear Alex,  A minor remark is that by the main theorems of Galois theory, we know that $K$ is Galois over $L$.  So you can replace $F$ by $L$ and hence assume that $F = L$.  This may make things psychologically simpler (since only two fields are involved, not three).  Regards,

Comment: @MattE，Yeah,I see.Thanks.

Comment: I think there is a typo. L should be generated by the traces of K over L with coefficients in F. So @MattE 's trick probably won't work here. As the case L=F is trivial...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that if $K=L(\alpha)$, then $L$ is generated over $F$ by $\text{Tr}_{K/L}(\alpha^i)$, $i\geq 0$. In order to do this, use [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) to identify $M=F(\{\text{Tr}_{K/L}(\alpha^i)\})$ with the subfield $N$ of $K$ generated over $F$ by the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$, then show that $N=L$.

Comment: you mean "this field" by the field generated over $F$ by $Tr_{K/L}(\alpha ^{i})$?

Comment: I guess my problem is that I don't know how to show that the field generated by the coefficients of $min(L,\alpha)$ is precisely $L$.

Comment: @Alex: Edited for clarity. In order to show that $N=L$, consider degrees. We obviously have $N\subseteq L$, and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$ is a fortiori irreducible in $N$. Since $N(\alpha) = L(\alpha) = K$, it follows that...

Comment: ,Oh, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alex: You are most welcome.

Comment: Do Newton's identities work here in positive characteristic?

Comment: @seaturtles Hmm! Good point...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: take the trace of a normal basis generator.

Comment: My problem is why the trace generates $L$ instead of a subfield of $L$.

Comment: @Alex Have you tried anything? Do you have any thoughts? My advice is to think in terms of modules (over group algebras), not fields. Do you know what the normal basis theorem is? I really, really don't want to spoil the argument for you.

Comment: I know the statement of the normal basis theorem, which claims that $\exists a \in K,\ s.t.\sigma(a)$  form a basis of $K$ over $F$.And the conjugations with respect to elements in $Gal(K/L)$ should also give a basis of $K$ over $L$. But I don't know how to proceed onward.

Comment: @Alex Then you just check when is the trace of a normal basis generator, call it $\beta$, is fixed by an element in Gal(K/F). The answer is iff the element is actually in Gal(K/L). Then by the Fundamental Theorem in Galois Theory, we may conclude that F($\beta$)=L.