# How to find $\mathbb Q(\zeta)^H?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Determine  a polynomial of degree  $7$  whose  Galois group  is cyclic  of order $7$?

I found the  answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/836420/557708)

It  is written that

> Let $\zeta = \exp(2\pi i/29)$ be a primitive 29th root of unity.
> Then the field $\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q$ has Galois group
> $$G = (\mathbb Z/29\mathbb Z)^\times \simeq \mathbb Z/28 \mathbb Z \simeq \mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/7 \mathbb Z .$$
> Since 2 is a primitive root mod 29 (a generator of $(\mathbb Z/29\mathbb Z)^\times$), this Galois group is generated by the automorphism $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^2$.
> Furthermore, an element of order 4 can by found by the seventh power of this automorphism, namely $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^{2^7} = \zeta^{12}$.

> Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^{12}$, which is cyclic of order 4.
> Then $G/H \simeq \mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$ is the Galois group of the fixed field $K := \mathbb Q(\zeta)^H$ over $\mathbb Q$.

> Now all we have to do is find the minimal polynomial of a generator for $K/\mathbb Q$.
> Since $\zeta$ generates $\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q$, the traces $\operatorname{Tr}_H(\zeta^i)$ generate $K/\mathbb Q$.

> Let
> $$\xi = \operatorname{Tr}_H(\zeta) = \sum_{\sigma \in H} \sigma(\zeta)= \zeta + \zeta^{12} + \zeta^{28} + \zeta^{17}$$
> By solving a large system of linear equations involving the powers of $\xi$ (or using a computer to do so), we find that $\xi$ has minimal polynomial

> $$f(x) = x^7 + x^6 - 12x^5 - 7x^4 + 28x^3 + 14x^2 - 9x + 1$$

**My  confusion'**:Why is  $G/H \simeq \mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$  the Galois group of the fixed field $K := \mathbb Q(\zeta)^H$ over $\mathbb Q?$

**My thinking** :let  $H=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$. we know  that  fixed field of  $H$ is  the  set of  element fixed by every automorphism in $H$

I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^G=\mathbb{Q}$

**My question**:How to find $\mathbb Q(\zeta)^H?$

Comment: As mentioned in linked answer (also repeated as a part of your post) the desired fixed field is $\mathbb{Q} (\zeta)^H= \mathbb{Q} (\xi) $.

Comment: Your confusion is handled by Galois correspondence, just note that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: For cyclotomic extensions the best treatment for explicit construction of fixed fields is the one given by Gauss in his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*. I have written some blog posts on Gauss theory of periods which you may find useful: [post 1](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/12/gauss-and-regular-polygons-gaussian-periods.html?m=0), [post 2](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/12/gauss-and-regular-polygons-gaussian-periods-contd.html?m=0).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for the link. You wrote it in a simple language that everyone can understand.