# $K/F$ is a Galois extension, show that any intermediate field $L$ is generated by the traces of elements from $K$ over $L$

Tags: galois-theory

This is an exercise in Morandi's Field & Galois Theory. The question has already been answered: [if $K/F$ is a Galois extension, show that any intermediate field $L$ is generated by the traces of elements from $K$ over $L$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812039/841725)

Although the answer using Newton's identity is illuminating, it cannot solve the problem when $\operatorname{char}F$ is $p$. By the way, to deal with the case when $\operatorname{char}F$ is 0, considering $\operatorname{Tr}_{K/L}(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in L$ is quite easy. Futhermore, can the similar statement hold for norm, that is to say, any intermediate field $L$ is generated by the norms of elements from $K$ over $L$, which is the following exercise in the book. The former technique of using Newton's identity cannot work this time and it's hard to disprove this question.

Comment: Ooops, your title ....use dollar signs for math symbols, not $\%$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $K/F$ separable the primitive element theorem gives that

$$K=F(a)=L(a)=L[x]/(f(x)), \qquad f(x)=\prod_{j=1}^d (x-a_j)=\sum_{m=0}^d c_m x^m\in L[x]$$
$$[K:F(c_0,\ldots,c_d)]\le d \quad \implies \quad L=F(c_0,\ldots,c_d)$$

From the [Newton identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), if all the traces are $0$ then each $k c_k=0$ so that $f(x)=g(x^p)$ and $K/L$ is not separable.

Whence $K/F$ separable implies that $Tr_{K/L}$ is not identically zero and hence it is surjective $K\to L$.

As you see the Galois hypothesis is superfluous.

Comment: “and hence it is surjective” how do you get this?

Comment: If $Tr_{K/L}(b)\ne 0$ then $Tr_{K/L}(bL)=L$